# How to make difference between folders and files

Tags: javascript

I am stuck in making difference between folders and files in Javascript. In this problem:

1. If I am trying to drag any folder then there should show any warning message and
2. If I am dragging any files(like zip file, rar file, doc file, txt file etc.) (If file name is like this way:- aparna.verma then also it should treat as file only not as folder or if file name is aparna-verma then also it should treat as file only not as folder.) then show warning message.
3. I used this line of code:

> ```
> if (new_file.type !== '') 
> {
>     new_list.push(new_file);
> }
> ```

Comment: I'm sorry, could you repeat the question?

Comment: If I am dragging folders then show me the warning message that "this is folder" and  if I am dragging the files then show me warning messages that "this is files". I want to see the difference between in  folders and in any Files.

Comment: Please give me any suggestion on this,please help me.

Comment: Might be an idea if you posted a 'complete' example, either above or on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: If File name is followed by "." or "-" then also it should be consider in files only not as folder,eg-file name is "aparna.verma" or "aparna-verma".

Comment: If I am dragging any type of documents then it should show the warning message "that these are documents" and if I am dragging any folder then it should show warning message that "these are folders".